# Inline Audio recorder that works on all browsers

Tags: safari, audio-recording, web-mediarecorder

I need to integrate an inline audio recorder for a web app and went through following -

- [MediaRecorder](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediarecorder)
- [Recorder.js](https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/)
- [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs)

I tested the above for Chrome, Firefox and Safari. None of the above solutions worked for Safari (version 12.1.1).

I understand that Safari has been kind of late to the game but I also expected a [polyfill](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) to work.

Could someone suggest the best way out here?

Answer (score 0):

The [VMSG](https://github.com/Kagami/vmsg) solution described in a [medium blog article](https://blog.addpipe.com/recording-mp3-audio-in-html5-using-vmsg-a-webassembly-library-based-on-lame/) just worked on all browsers including safari (both mobile and desktop)